# @RequestParam, name vs value attributes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am reading the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html#name--) of the `@RequestParam` annotation in Spring MVC.

What is the difference between **name** and **value** attributes?

The documentation says:

> value : Alias for name().
>
> name: The name of the request parameter to bind to.

What does it mean *Alias for name()* ?

Suppose you have:

`http://localhost:8080/springmvc/hello/101?param1=10&param2=20`

```
public String getDetails(
    @RequestParam(value="param1", required=true) String param1,
    @RequestParam(value="param2", required=false) String param2){
        ...
}
```

for example, `value="param1"` is the name of request-parameter to bind, while `String param1` is the object to bind to.

How could I use `name` attribute here?

Comment: What do you think **alias for name** means... That is pretty obvious imho.

Comment: please have a look to the edit

Comment: Its a good question.  Value usually means, well, the value stored in the variable.  Why they would use it as an alias for name or id is beyond me.

Comment: The reason they have `value` as an alias for `name` is that `value` has a special meaning in annotations. The `value` annotation parameter is the default, allowed to appear in parentheses without a parameter name specified. Thus you can have `@RequestParam("foo")` instead of `@RequestParam(value="foo")`. They apparently thought that `name` was more descriptive, so you can use `@RequestParam(value="foo")` as well. But they have to support `value` or `@RequestParam("foo")` wouldn't work. See [Annotations Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Functionality of both are same with just different alternative naming. Whichever you prefer to use you will get same functionality. Any one can be used but if you used both make sure to use same value for them, otherwise you will get exception.

You are allowed to use like this:

```
@RequestParam(value="param1", required=true)
@RequestParam(name="param1", required=true)
@RequestParam(value="param1", required=true, name="param1")
```

But not this:

```
@RequestParam(value="param1", required=true, name="param3")
```

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html